# Is it possible to create an accumulated log-based metric in GCP/stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metrics, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to create a metric to accumulate over a full month. In other words, I want to count the occurrence of a certain entry in the logs over a calendar month to say at the end of the month "there were X events". Is this possible? I have seen such accumulated metrics in stackdriver (for example the bytes ingested by stackdriver logging by month) so I know they exist but I can't find how to create one using counters or distributions, which look like the only possible options for log-based metrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log-based counter metrics count the number of entries that match the filter every minute and do not aggregate over the month.  Currently, the only way to accomplish this would be to use something like [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export) to consume the LBM and re-write it as a cumulative custom metric.

Answer (score 0):

If one looks at [Overview of log-based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) it appears that this may be the key.  If we assume that log records are written into the Stackdriver log, you can define a metric counter that fires each time a matching log record is seen.  This counter metric can the be used to build a dashboard or fire an alert where you can aggregate the count over a period of time.